# "how much she got paid" OR "how much she had got paid"

Tags: tense, past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

I am confused about what tense I should use here:

> She had had no idea how much she got paid before her first payday.

OR

> She had had no idea how much she had got paid before her first payday.

OR (could this work?)

> She had had no idea how much she would get paid before her first payday.

Comment: The third is definitely the best, and the second doesn't make sense. Before her _first_ payday, obviously she had not yet been paid anything.

Comment: You probably don't want Past Perfect ***had had*** there. *When she started last week she **had** no idea how much she **would be** paid [**until** her first payday]*. You'd need an unusual context to justify ***how much she had [got / gotten / been] paid*** (wages were paid, but she hasn't/hadn't yet checked her bank statement?).

Comment: @KateBunting thank you very much for enlightening me!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica okay so I can just use past simple, then? But, I don't get why I would need that unusual context? Would you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: *I went home after I finished work.* There's nothing to stop me using Past Perfect to *explicitly* convey the sequence of events over and above what's already there because of pragmatic logic and the word "after" *(I went home after I **had** finished work)*. But it's completely unnecessary, and that extra highlighted word would rarely be included. If you don't know you ***need*** Past Perfect, just don't bother with it.